# How to resolve Firebase error for oAuth in Swift. FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

My create auth user method is no longer working and I’m getting an error that I haven’t seen before. I checked the GoogleService-Info.plist and all the values match my firebase dashboard. Even re-downloaded it to be sure. I’ve toggled the Sign-in method and also enabled the Identity Toolkit API from the Google Cloud Platform.

Found some okay answers on Stack Overflow but didn’t relate to the ‘status = “PERMISION_DENIED” internal error.  Any feedback would be great!  - Here is the full error message

```
Error creating Auth createUserWith(email:password:completionUser:completion:) 
        Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, 
        print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo= . 
        {error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has 
        occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., 
        NSUnderlyingError=0x60400025f7d0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain 
        Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
            code = 403;
            errors =     (
                    {
                domain = global;
                message = "Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.firebase.auth.v1.IdentityIdaasAuthenticationService.SignUp are blocked.";
                reason = forbidden;
            }
        );
        message = "Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.firebase.auth.v1.IdentityIdaasAuthenticationService.SignUp are blocked.";
        status = "PERMISSION_DENIED";
    }}}} An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.
```

Here's a screen shot of my code and the rules in Firebase.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: check that your allowed domains include your utilized domains `mydomain.com` in each of your oAuth provider settings pages.

Comment: I believe that the oAuth provider is set up correctly. The only way to sign up via 'Sign-in providers' is Email/password. The authorized domains are just the local host default and the projectName.firebaseapp.com (default).

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't resolve the underlining issue. However, I deleted the project in firebase and made a new one, downloaded the new p.list and my create function is now all good!

Answer (score 1):

I add the domain that I was using in firebase console. That worked for me. https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400741?authuser=0&hl=en