# flutter firebase sign in with apple [firebase_auth/internal-error]

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm using flutterfire cli.

flutter: [firebase_auth/internal-error] Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c4e940 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c60c30 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 565, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 5d0a2020 7d0a7d0a }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={

```
class ContinueWithApple extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContinueWithApple({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SizedBox(
      width: size.width * 0.85,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () => _signInWithApple(context),
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset("assets/applelogo.png", height: 20, width: 20),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            const Text(
              "Continue with Apple",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _signInWithApple(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
        ],
      );

      final credential = OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(
        idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
        accessToken: appleCredential.authorizationCode,
      );

      await _authenticateAndStoreUserData(credential, appleCredential);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      CustomSnackbar.show(context, e.toString());
    }
  }
```

This is my code. Why am i getting the error and how can i resolve?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359194/how-to-resolve-firebase-error-for-oauth-in-swift-firautherrordomain-code-17999 it seems that this may be caused by missing a domain for OAuth redirects. Also see https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400741?authuser=0&hl=en